# How to pass a string, as well as other variables, into a gnome-terminal

Tags: python, bash, discord, gnome-terminal

I am trying to create a Python file that will launch the Python scripts for 4 different Discord bots. I am struggling to figure out how to pass the variables to the gnome terminal.

For example:

```
paths = [
    [
        "Bot 1 Name",
        "Bot 1 Path/Bot1.py"
    ],
    [
        "Bot 2 Name",
        "Bot 2 Path/Bot2.py"
    ]
]

for bot in paths:
    os.system(f"""gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'echo Starting up {bot[0]}; python "{bot[1]}"; exec bash'""")
```

However, this doesn't work as the path to each bot needs to be surrounded by some form of quotation marks otherwise the terminal won't see it as one argument.
I've tried a bunch of different arrangements of quotation marks, as well as a few other methods, but none of which force the terminal to realise that the value of `{bot[1]}` needs to be surrounded by quotations.

Ideally, the terminal should be receiving the command as follows:
`gnome-terminal -- bash -c "echo Starting up Bot 1; python '~/Bot1.py'; exec bash"`
Or somthing similar that functions the same.

Any advice?

Comment: You could try escaping the spaces in your paths instead, e.g. "Bot\ 2\ Path/Bot2.py", you can use Python's string.replace for escaping all spaces automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure this is what u want or not. You can use python format string function.

```
for bot in paths:
   os.system("gnome-terminal -- bash -c \"echo Starting up {}; python '{}'; exec bash\"".format(bot[0], bot[1]))
```

By using with print function, you'll get a same output as u mentioned.

```
for bot in paths:
   print("gnome-terminal -- bash -c \"echo Starting up {}; python '{}'; exec bash\"".format(bot[0], bot[1]))
```

> gnome-terminal -- bash -c "echo Starting up Bot 1 Name; python 'Bot 1
>   Path/Bot1.py'; exec bash"
>
> gnome-terminal -- bash -c "echo Starting up Bot 2 Name; python 'Bot 2
>   Path/Bot2.py'; exec bash"

Comment: I don't know why this works and I'll try and figure it out on my own, but thank you. I really appreciate it!